# MC Personalization: Purchase Event triggers and is shown in Event Stream but LTV remains the same

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, interaction-studio, personalization, evergage

I am beginning to set up Marketing Cloud Personalization (former Interaction Studio) and now have to fire purchase Events through the Event API.

Currently, the detection of Purchase Events works and the Event is shown in the Event Stream, but whatever I try, the event is not reflected on the User itself that bought the product, what I mean by that is that his LTV(= LifeTimeValue) doesn't get updated, but there is an event when I send the request.

I used this as a base for my request and I'm using Postman to test those requests:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/personalization/guide/item-actions.html?q=lineItem

```
{
    "action": "Product Purchased",
    "source": {
        "channel": "Server"
    },
    "user": {
        "attributes": {
            "customerId": "testUser",
            "locale": "de_AT"
        }
    },
    "itemAction": "Purchase",
    ".order": {
        "Product": {
            "orderId": "abcdefg",
            "totalValue?": 37.99,
            "currency?": "EUR",
            ".lineItems": [{
                "lineItem": {
                    "catalogObjectId": "testProduct",
                    "catalogObjectType": "Product",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "price?": 37.99,
                    "currency?": "EUR"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the response I get

```
{
    "id": "64d2484ee746b80af868566a",
    "campaignResponses": [],
    "errorCode": 0,
    "persistedUserId": {
        "entityId": "5Ie0GI-tTSNUoD3qZh15SgO_Vq2HH9EH-EwUDHQABPXfridKqaX5of8n35gn9y1a2gYU6Wb5loimlx5OwhkthLh03mk_8p_dO8KI2SnXeSI",
        "accountId": ""
    },
    "resolvedUserId": "39648ae8f2aa69e830ca1ae2"
}
```

I don't know what could be wrong with the request, since the event seems to fire, and it is also shown on the user that an event happened

I'd appreciate any help.